# Выбор формы jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Имеется форма, в которой необходимо выбрать условие поиска (искать по фамилии или по номеру карточки), и чтоб при нажатии на кнопку "поиск" под формой загружалась форма с результатом.

В результирующей форме указывались параметры и сохранялись (записывались в базу). Как это сделать без перезагрузки страницы. Понятно, что на аяксе, но как?

Форма выбора параметров поиска

```
<table width="305" height="161" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="144"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio" />
    Номер карточки</td>
    <td width="145"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="radio2" />
      Фамилия</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="      Поиск      " />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Форма ввода параметров (результирующая)

```
<table width="325" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="142">Номер карточки</td>
    <td width="167"><input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ФИО</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Пол</td>
    <td><select name="select" id="select">
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Образование</td>
    <td><select name="select2" id="select2">
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Сохранить" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Отменить" />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #big_form {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<table width="305" height="161" border="1">
<form action="/myscript.php" id="small_form">
  <tr>
    <td width="144"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="radio" />
    номер карточки</td>
    <td width="145"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="radio2" />
      Фамилия</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield1_name" id="textfield1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield2_name" id="textfield2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="search_button" value="      Поиск      " />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>

<table width="325" border="1" id="big_form">
  <tr>
    <td width="142">Номер карточки</td>
    <td width="167"><input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ФИО</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="textfield3" id="textfield3" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Пол</td>
    <td><select name="select" id="select">
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Образование</td>
    <td><select name="select2" id="select2">
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Сохранить" />
    </div></td>
    <td><div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Отменить" />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#small_form").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var url = $(this).attr("action");
                if ($("#radio1").is(':checked')) {
                    $.post (
                        url, {
                            textfield1_name: $("#textfield1").val()
                        }, function(response) {
                            //response - это то, что выдаст сервер на такой пост
                            //запрос, следовательно тут должен быть скрипт вставляющий
                            //ответы в форму, это делается так:
                            //$("#textfield3").val("часть ответа");
                            $("#big_form").fadeIn(1000);//затем отображаем форму
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    $.post (
                        url, {
                            textfield1_name: $("#textfield2").val()
                        }, function(response) {
                            //аналогично
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

ПС обратите внимание, что для избежания проблем все элементы должны иметь разные id, в рамках целой страницы, а не одной формы. Плюс, наверно радио-кнопки должны иметь одно имя, т.к. иначе они могут быть нажаты вместе.

Answer (score 2):

Читаем описание функции $.ajax() [тут](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-ajax/).
Если кратко, то вешаем эту функцию на отправку формы, указывает в ней все необходимые параметры. В success обрабатываем принятый ответ (вашу результирующую форму).
Не забудьте указать return false; после функции $.ajax() - это предотвратит отправку формы стандартными средствами(с перезагрузкой страницы).

Если будут какие-то вопросы - задавайте, подскажу. Код обработчика не помогу написать - я специализируюсь на питоне и джанге, а не на пхп)

Answer (score 0):

это что еще за переключатель radio с разными именами? ну ИДшники разные - понимаю(и то если честно то искать отмеченный легче если один ИД у одной группы радио - сделай его тоже например id='radio'). разные  value -  само собой. но name? если хочешь чтобы форма правильно работала и радио был именно радио а не чекбоксом то ставишь одно имя и по определение чека идет через

```
rad=$("#radio").is(':checked').attr('value');
textfield2=$("#textfield2").attr('value');
textfield=$("#textfield").attr('value');
```

и передавай себе все эти поля а в пхп разбирайся что в радио пришло по тому и ищи. зачем мучать яваскрипт проверками если-то. а если ты еще захочешь вариант поиска то опять писать еще раз если то???